# Cancel console printing

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have the following config file:

```xml
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
        <param name="File" value="D:\log.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="20" />
        <maximumFileSize value="4MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Every line I am logging is written to Console as well, how can I cancel it?

I want it to be appended to the log.txt file ONLY, without anything in Console.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382479/how-do-i-disable-log4net-status-messages-to-the-console

Answer (score 0):

Either you have added console appender programmatically, or this configuration file is not used by log4net. Log4net don't add any default appenders (like default `TraceListener` in .net). And this configuration specifies only `RollingFileAppender`. So, verify which configuration file is used, and whether some appenders added in the code.